# Proving - ring theory and homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So I am having a lot of trouble proving this. It was for an assignment due tuesday, but the prof said I can have a bit of extra time with this question.

Please do not give me the answer because I am sure my prof is on this website :P

okay so the question is as follows:

> Let $R$ be a ring with identity. Show that the map $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ given by $f(k) = k1_R$ is a homomorphism.

So obviously I went about proving the axioms thinking the $k$ and $1_R$ are integer products. BUT as my prof pointed out, there not. Here is the explanation on his course webpage.

> A couple of remarks about Assignment 8
>   problems:
>   In exercise 25, when H'ford writes
>   something like  $k1_R$  , where  k is an integer, he of course is not
>   speaking of a  PRODUCT of elements of
>   the ring  R.  Given an element  a of
>   R, the  inductive definition of  ka, 
>   k in ZZ, in connection with the 
>   definition of the characteristic of a
>   ring, about which  you folks had an
>   assignment problem, was this:
>
> 0a := 0_R,
>
> and, for all  k  in  |N,  (k+1)a :=
>   ka + a.
>
> Also, if  k  is a negative integer,
>   then  ka := -((-k)a).
>
> I believe we defined finite sums
>   inductively a long time ago.  One
>   defines  0a  as above, and we could
>   then use our earlier inductive
>   definition and just say that, for each
>   k  in  ZZ^+,
>   $$ka=\sum_{j=1}^k a$$
>
> And then define  ka  for negative
>   integers  k  as above.

so how do I use his definition of what $k$ is and how do I apply it to my proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to show that $(m\cdot n)1_R=(m1_R)\cdot(n1_R)$ for all integers $m$ and $n$.

If $m$ and $n$ are non-negative this follows from your definition $ka:=\sum_{j=1}^k a$.

The general case is then an easy consequence of the axioms. You should try to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

So, I guess that for $m$ and $n$ positive you need to prove that
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^m\,1_R\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\,1_R\right)=
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{mn}\,1_R\right).
$$
How many addends you have when you apply the distributive property on the LHS ?

Then you have to come up with something for when $m$ and $n$ are not both positive.